# What is wrong with running unix processes with &?

Tags: shell, unix

I have seen tools to daemonize processes.

But I have seen that:

```
some_command &
```

Runs process in a daemonized way, is this way bad? how is this way called?

## Update

My doubt is that I am calling that command inside an ssh session, will the process last after closing ssh session?

Comment: For your last question: It depends. If you start it with `noup`, it may last. Otherwise, it depends on how the process responds to the HUP signal - most programs will simply terminate.

Answer (score 3):

That's not daemonized, that's simply running it as a background process.

A true dameon is a lot more involved; see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computer_software)#Creation.

Comment: @juanpastas: Cons compared to what?

Comment: cons in cpu or memory usage, or general cons, like missing pid, I don't know if any other.

Answer (score 1):

The & is an important little character in UNIX; it means "run the command in the background"; i.e., detach it from the window it was started from, so it does not block the command line.

Should the program ever try to read from the terminal window, it will be suspended, until the user "brings it to the foreground"; i.e., brings it to the state it would have had without the & to begin with.

To bring a program to the foreground, use "fg" or "%". If you have more than one background job to choose from ("jobs" will show you), then use for example "%2" to choose the second one.

Important:

If you forget to give the & at the end of line, and the process blocks the command input to the terminal window, you can put the process in the background "after the fact", by using Ctrl-Z. The process is suspended, and you get the command prompt back. The first thing you should do then is probably to give the command "bg", that resumes the process, but now in the background.

http://www.astro.ku.dk/comp-phys/tutorials/background.shtml

Comment: No cons as long as the program doesn't require the use of the tty. Otherwise, it may crash or quit or if it tries to write to the tty, it may just stop running (SIGTTOU), in which case you can resume it with the `fg` job control command. Other than that, there are no cons that I can think of, except maybe if a shell doesn't support job control...